# jQuery curtain scroller app

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to build a curtain slider - much like what is used on the Apple site - http://www.apple.com/30-years/

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/405/

I've created the following code - I need to add listeners to detect the mouse hovering over the far left/far right sides of the page - and then invoke an exponential slide.

```
var curtainSlider = {
    invoke: function(el){
         var that = this;

         var list = $(el + " ul").find("li");
         this.initialListWidth = list.outerWidth(true);

        list
            .mouseover(function() {
                console.log("over"); 
                that.expand(this);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                console.log("out");
                that.contract(this);
            });         
    },
    expand: function(el){
        var that = this;

        $(el).stop().animate({
            width: that.initialListWidth*2
        },400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    },
    contract: function(el){
        var that = this;

        $(el).stop().animate({
            width: that.initialListWidth
        },400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }

}


$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    curtainSlider.invoke("#curtain");
});
```

Comment: I've added a page listener if the mouse hits the far left/far right. Not sure how to develop an incrementing animation for the entire slider - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/407/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://timemapper.okfnlabs.org/

Comment: Added some test pictures - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/413/

Comment: Hello Kenan, I looked at the example - but it doesn't mimic a form of incrementing animation on page position events

Comment: I've got it to scroll - when you hover over the left (the right is to far offscreen because of the iframe) but I am keen to improve the animation. It seeems juttery and awkward.  http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/419/

Comment: I've enhanced it with a spectrum fade in - but the hover events on the outer edges - and the gradual speed up or speed down of the scroll is not right - how do I improve it or refactor it accordingly - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/430/

Comment: Expanded out the cells more - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/431/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**LATEST CODE - complete integration - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/538/ **

I have stabilized this version of the scroller. - This curtains the images and spectrum fades them on start up. It repositions the a elements so the image is more centrally aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/432/

I've separated out the code responsible for moving the slider unit, with an acceleration/deceleration. Its this part of the application I wish to focus on now.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/434/

I've tried to push the pagex variable into the animation part to help manipulate the duration of the animation. How can this be stabilized/improved on. I am finding it hard to reverse engineer the apple 30 year slider.

```
var curtainSlider = {
    bindEvents: function(){
        var that = this;    
        $("body").on("mousemove",function(event) {
            if (event.pageX < 50) {
                // animate curtain left
                console.log("curtain left");
                that.scroll("l", event.pageX);
            }

            if (event.pageX > (window.width - 50)) {
                // animate curtain right
                console.log("curtain right");                
                that.scroll("r", window.width - event.pageX);
            }
        });    

    },
    scroll: function(direction, leveler){
        var charge = "-";
        if(direction == "r"){
            charge = "+";
        }

        $('#curtainholder #slider').animate({
            left: charge+"="+leveler
        },400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    },
    invoke: function(el){
         var that = this;
        this.bindEvents();
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    curtainSlider.invoke("#curtain");
});
```

Comment: Latest on enhancements on the scroll - but juttering and not yet sensitive to the mouse position on the edges. - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/485/

Comment: I've managed to get some listeners in place to adjust the sensitivity/duration of the sliding by the mouse position on the hot spots. Would like some help though in fine tuning the animation - it still seems juttery to me - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/509/

Comment: I've reduced the checkTime var to 50ms - it seems more fluent - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/510/

Comment: Improved the code - so it locks off to stop the slider being displaced too far left or right - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/517/